Anime with a cyclops robot summoned with a card
I'm looking for an anime I watched on TV in 2018.
All I can remember is that the main character could summon a giant cyclops robot with a card ig. There were 3 variants of the robot: normal, gold, and titanium/platinum. 
Does anyone remember this?

I tried to put the question in a better shape, but could not guess what you mean by "card ig". Also, consider having a look at the Tips for asking Story Identification questions and adding other details to your question to improve the chance someone is able to answer.
